# calling sqlj.install_jar from jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw, java-stored-procedures

I have a python snippet that I try to port to java. The aim is Gradle but I could not get that to work, so I figured I would start with plain JDBC. The python code looks like this:

```
import argparse
import ibm_db
import sys

def main(hostname, database, username, password):

    connstr = f"DATABASE={database};HOSTNAME={hostname};PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID={username}; PWD={password}"
    conn = ibm_db.connect(connstr, "", "")
    s1 = ibm_db.prepare(conn, "call sqlj.install_jar('file:/tmp/commons.jar', 'StringUtil_TEST')")
    ibm_db.execute(s1, ())
    # print(ibm_db.fetch_tuple(s1)[0])
    ibm_db.commit(conn)
    sys.exit(0)
```

and works. The jar file ends up in ~/sqllib/function/jar/DB2INST1 on the target host as expected.

I've looked at several examples in java and try to mimic them, but I always end up with an error (most of them likely because I'm illiterate when it comes to java). The current code I have is:

```
   public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(<host>, <user>, <passwd>);
            CallableStatement callStmt1 = null;
            callStmt1 = con.prepareCall("call sqlj.install_jar('" + "file:/tmp/commons.jar" + "', 'StringUtil_TEST2')");

            // tried this as well 
            // callStmt1 = con.prepareCall("call sqlj.install_jar('" + "file:/tmp/commons.jar" + "', 'StringUtil_TEST2', 0)");

            callStmt1.execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println(e.);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

compiled as:

```
#> javac -cp db2jcc4.jar aa.java
```

and run as:

```
#> java -cp .:db2jcc4.jar Aa
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR;PROCEDURE, DRIVER=4.29.24
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:810)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.c(k9.java:2844)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.d(k9.java:2828)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.a(k9.java:2254)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k_.a(k_.java:8277)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.i(ab.java:204)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.e(ab.java:133)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.d(p.java:63)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.av.m(av.java:190)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.am(k9.java:2249)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k_.bs(k_.java:3778)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k_.a(k_.java:4640)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.b(CallableStatement.java:136)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.a(CallableStatement.java:105)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:95)
    at Aa.main(aa.java:28)
```

Meaning of

```
  SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "<routine-name>" of type
  "<routine-type>" having compatible arguments was found.
```

I would have expected that error to happen during prepare, but it happens during execute
so I'm not sure what to make out of it.

Does anyone have a working snippet to share for calling sqlj.install_jar from jdbc?

Comment: Same symptom for me (Db2-LUW v11.5.6.0).  Fortunately the alternative method `sqlj.DB2_INSTALL_JAR` works ok . Some regression maybe.

Comment: @mao, I looked at that as well, but if I get it right the first argument should be a blob then. Regardless I could not get it to work with URL, BLOB or STRING. This will only be used against a db2 luw database, so I would be most grateful if you could post a snippet of an example that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Connection con = null;
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(<host>, <user>, <passwd>);
DB2Connection db2con = (DB2Connection) con;
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/tmp/commons.jar");
db2con.installDB2JavaStoredProcedure(is, (int) is.getChannel().size(), "StringUtil_TEST2");
...

// if replaceDB2JavaStoredProcedure is used it is necessary
// to refresh classes to load the new jar
CallableStatement callStmt1 = null;
callStmt1 = db2con.prepareCall("call sqlj.refresh_classes()");
callStmt1.execute();
```

Comment: I can confirm that this worked. I'll have a look at mao:s answer now

Comment: I added an example for refresh classes. Feel free to revert it if you find it inappropriate in any way

Answer (score 1):

I get the same -440 symptom as your question, on Db2-LUW v11.5.6.0 from jdbc when I call `sqlj.install_jar` .

Possibly some regression or mistake by me.

It may also be worthwhile to compare the behaviour of method `DB2Connection.installDB2JavaStoredProcedure` (which supposedly runs `sqlj.install_jar` )

But the alternate method `sqlj.DB2_INSTALL_JAR` works ok from jdbc for me currently.

Sample below based on IBM's example code, and I run it locally on the Db2-LUW server so use passwordless style url.

Note that if you need to make it re-runnable, you have to extend it, to check `sysibm.sysjarobjects` for the jar_id , use `sqlj.replace_jar` and/or `sqlj.remove_jar` and `sqlj.refresh_classes()` as appropriate. For that reason I prefer to use shell-script instead of jdbc for orchestrating my build scripts, at the cost of having a properly configured Db2-client at the build hostname. The shell scripts are shorter and easier to manage than jdbc code in my case.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


        public class installj {
            public static void main(String[] args)  {
                String url = "jdbc:db2:sample";   // url syntax for passwordless connection local on Db2-server
                String user = "";
                String password = "";
                Connection con;
                CallableStatement callStmt;
                String returnedVarchar="";
                String jarid = "MYJARID";
                String jarfile = "/home/user1/test/jarname.jar";


                try {
                    Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver") ;

                    // the URL format is specifically for a Type-2 passwordless local connection
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                    con.setAutoCommit(false);
                    File aFile = new File(jarfile);
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(aFile);
                    CallableStatement stmt;
                    String sql = "Call SQLJ.DB2_INSTALL_JAR(?, ?, ?)";
                    stmt = con.prepareCall(sql);
                    stmt.setBinaryStream(1, inputStream, (int)aFile.length());
                    stmt.setString(2, jarid);
                    stmt.setInt(3, 0);
                    boolean isrs = stmt.execute();
                    stmt.close();
                    System.out.println("\n\nInstallation of JAR succeeded\n\n");
                    con.commit();
                    con.close();
                }

                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.err.println("\nCaught exception FileNot Found\n");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.err.println("Could not load JDBC driver");
                    System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.err.println("---> SQLException information\n");
                    while (ex != null) {
                        System.err.println("\nError msg: " + ex.getMessage());
                        System.err.println("\nSQLSTATE: " + ex.getSQLState());
                        System.err.println("\nError code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        ex = ex.getNextException();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that your code works for me as well. We will run flyway via gradle inside a docker container. I got the evil eye when I suggested that we put python in there for this task, I don't think I will survive if I suggest that we should pull in Db2:-) As for  Idempotency I think we will just catch the exception and then call replace. I will accept Marks answer, but I could as well have accepted yours

Comment: @Lennart no need for a full Db2-client, the ODBC-CLI client suffices (tiny footprint) and still scriptable with plain shell or cmd.