# creating sql function implemented in java via flyway

Tags: db2, flyway, db2-luw

I'm trying to create a function like:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
@
```

from flyway. The jar file is already installed on the server, and I can create the function without problems via clp:

```
~]$ db2 -v -td@ -f aa.sql 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

I also tried creating via dbeaver from my local machine without a problem:

```
Updated Rows    0
Query   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
      RETURNS INTEGER
      RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
      FENCED THREADSAFE
      DETERMINISTIC
      NO SQL
      LANGUAGE JAVA
      PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
      EXTERNAL NAME
    'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
      NO EXTERNAL ACTION
Finish time Tue Jan 11 22:14:46 CET 2022
```

But if I try to run the same file from flyway:

```
]$ flyway -schemas=NYA_FLYWAY -table="FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" -driver=${driver} -url=jdbc:db2://${host}:${port}/${db} -user=${username} -password=${passwd} -jarDirs=${jarDirs} -locations="filesystem:${upgradedir}" migrate
A new version of Flyway is available
Upgrade to Flyway 8.4.1: https://rd.gt/2X0gakb
Flyway Community Edition 8.0.5 by Redgate
Database: jdbc:db2://130.239.91.21:50000/NYA (DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5)
Successfully validated 36 migrations (execution time 00:00.027s)
Current version of schema "NYA_FLYWAY": 22.223.100.3
Migrating schema "NYA_FLYWAY" to version "22.223.100.4"
ERROR: Migration of schema "NYA_FLYWAY" to version "22.223.100.4" failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
ERROR: Migration V22.223.100.4__.sql failed
------------------------------------
SQL State  : 46008
Error Code : -20204
Message    : The user defined function or procedure "NYA.QUINT_2_UINT" was unable to map to a single Java method.. SQLCODE=-20204, SQLSTATE=46008, DRIVER=4.29.24
Location   : /home/lejo0004/Project/db-legacy/nya/src/main/resources/db/migration/V22.223.100/V22.223.100.4__.sql (/home/lejo0004/Project/db-legacy/nya/src/main/resources/db/migration/V22.223.100/V22.223.100.4__.sql)
Line       : 3
Statement  : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION

Caused by: Migration V22.223.100.4__.sql failed
------------------------------------
SQL State  : 46008
Error Code : -20204
Message    : The user defined function or procedure "NYA.QUINT_2_UINT" was unable to map to a single Java method.. SQLCODE=-20204, SQLSTATE=46008, DRIVER=4.29.24
Location   : /home/lejo0004/Project/db-legacy/nya/src/main/resources/db/migration/V22.223.100/V22.223.100.4__.sql (/home/lejo0004/Project/db-legacy/nya/src/main/resources/db/migration/V22.223.100/V22.223.100.4__.sql)
Line       : 3
Statement  : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION

Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: The user defined function or procedure "NYA.QUINT_2_UINT" was unable to map to a single Java method.. SQLCODE=-20204, SQLSTATE=46008, DRIVER=4.29.24
```

I'm using the same driver with dbeaver and flyway. I also tried running it from gradle with the same error. Any clue on what might cause this issue with flyway?

There are other functions in the jar as well and all that I have tried, share the same problem as described above

FWIW, the underlying function is [A Proposal for Proquints: Identifiers that are Readable, Spellable, and Pronounceable](https://arxiv.org/html/0901.4016)

EDIT:

The jar file is normally installed in a similar fashion as Mark demonstrated in [calling-sqlj-install-jar-from-jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219861/calling-sqlj-install-jar-from-jdbc) using gradle.

But to eliminate any errors there, I manually installed the jarfile on the server as:

```
[db2inst1@nya-01 ~]$ db2 "call sqlj.install_jar('file:///opt/nya/users/db2inst1/STRINGUTIL.jar', 'STRINGUTIL')"
SQL20201N  The install, replace or remove of "DB2INST1.STRINGUTIL" failed as 
the jar name is invalid.  SQLSTATE=46002

[db2inst1@nya-01 ~]$ db2 "call sqlj.replace_jar('file:///opt/nya/users/db2inst1/STRINGUTIL.jar', 'STRINGUTIL')"
DB20000I  The CALL command completed successfully.

[db2inst1@nya-01 ~]$ db2 "call sqlj.refresh_classes()"
DB20000I  The CALL command completed successfully.
```

Now, on the server I can:

```
[db2inst1@nya-01 ~]$ db2 connect

Database Connection Information
Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5.6.0
SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
Local database alias   = EKLN_N11

[db2inst1@nya-01 ~]$ db2 -v -td@ -f aa.sql 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 "VALUES NYA.QUINT_2_UINT('aabbccddee')"

1          
-----------
         17

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Using dbeaver from my workstation, against the same server/database,  also works fine (so jdbc does not seem to be a problem per se):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
@

VALUES NYA.QUINT_2_UINT('ddeeaabbccd') @

1      | 
-------+
1114113|
```

But if I try to run it from flyway on my workstation against the same server/database I get the error:

```
SQL State  : 46008
Error Code : -20204
Message    : The user defined function or procedure "NYA.QUINT_2_UINT" was unable to map to a single Java method.. SQLCODE=-20204, SQLSTATE=46008, DRIVER=4.29.24
```

The java code itself is not very exciting:

```
package se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures;

public class Proquint {
    ...
            static int quint2uint(String quint) {
            long res = 0;
            for (char c : quint.toCharArray()) {
                    int index = indexOf(uint2consonant, c);
                    if (index != -1) {
                            res <<= 4;
                            res += index;
                    } else {
                            index = indexOf(uint2vowel, c);
                            if (index != -1) {
                                    res <<= 2;
                                    res += index;
                            }
                    }
            }
            return (int) res;
    }
```

I used the same user/passwd for all 3 cases (clp, dbeaver. flyway)

EDIT2:

I did a small test program:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class tst {
 
        public static void main(String [] args) {
              String urlPrefix = "jdbc:db2:";
              String url;
              String user;
              String password;
              String dummy;
              Connection con;
              Statement stmt;
           ResultSet rs;
 
           System. out.println ("**** Enter class tst" );
           if (args.length !=3)
           {
             System. err.println ("Invalid value. First argument appended to " +
              "jdbc:db2: must specify a valid URL." );
             System. err.println ("Second argument must be a valid user ID." );
             System. err.println ("Third argument must be the password for the user ID.");
             System. exit(1);
           }
           url = urlPrefix + args[0];
           user = args[1];
           password = args[2];
           try {
              Class. forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
              System. out.println("**** Loaded the JDBC driver" );
              con = DriverManager. getConnection(url, user, password);
              con.setAutoCommit( false);
              System. out.println("**** Created a JDBC connection to the data source");
              stmt = con.createStatement();
              System. out.println("**** Created JDBC Statement object" );
 
              String s = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) ";
              s += "RETURNS INTEGER ";
              s += "RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT ";
              s += "FENCED THREADSAFE ";
              s += "DETERMINISTIC ";
              s += "NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA ";
              s += "EXTERNAL NAME 'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' ";
              s += "NO EXTERNAL ACTION";

              //stmt.executeUpdate(s);
              stmt.execute(s);

              System. out.println("**** Created function" );

              s = "values NYA.QUINT_2_UINT('aabbccddeeg')";
              rs = stmt.executeQuery(s);    
              while (rs.next()) {
                dummy = rs.getString(1);
                System. out.println("number = " + dummy);
              }
              System. out.println("**** Fetched all rows from JDBC ResultSet" );
              rs.close();
              System. out.println("**** Closed JDBC ResultSet" );
 
               // Close the Statement
               stmt.close();
               System. out.println("**** Closed JDBC Statement" );
 
               // Connection must be on a unit-of-work boundary to allow close
               con.commit();
               System. out.println ( "**** Transaction committed" );
 
               con.close();
               System. out.println("**** Disconnected from data source" );
               System. out.println("**** JDBC Exit from class tst - no errors" );
           }
           catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
              System. err.println("Could not load JDBC driver" );
               System. out.println("Exception: " + e);
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           catch(SQLException ex) {
              System. err.println("SQLException information" );
               while(ex!=null ) {
                 System. err.println ("Error msg: " + ex.getMessage());
                 System. err.println ("SQLSTATE: " + ex.getSQLState());
                 System. err.println ("Error code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
                 ex.printStackTrace();
                 ex = ex.getNextException(); // For drivers that support chained exceptions
               }
           }
       }
}
```

and compared the jdbc trace for that with a jdbc trace for flyway. The flyway trace looks like:

```
[jcc][Time:2022-01-13-12:22:49.714][Thread:main][Statement@275fe372]setEscapeProcessing (false) called
[jcc][Thread:main][SystemMonitor:start] 
[jcc][Time:2022-01-13-12:22:49.714][Thread:main][Statement@275fe372]execute (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS INTEGER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'STRINGUTIL:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' NO EXTERNAL ACTION) called
[jcc][Time:2022-01-13-12:22:49.714][Thread:main][Statement@275fe372]stmt_bidiTransform (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS INTEGER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'STRINGUTIL:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' NO EXTERNAL ACTION) called
[jcc][Time:2022-01-13-12:22:49.714][Thread:main][Statement@275fe372]stmt_bidiTransform not enabled (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS INTEGER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'STRINGUTIL:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' NO EXTERNAL ACTION) called
[jcc][t4][time:2022-01-13-12:22:49.714][Thread:main][tracepoint:1][Request.flush]
```

whereas the test program:

```
[jcc][Thread:main][SystemMonitor:start] 
[jcc][Time:2022-01-13-12:22:28.089][Thread:main][Statement@1372ed45]execute (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS INTEGER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' NO EXTERNAL ACTION) called
[jcc][Time:2022-01-13-12:22:28.089][Thread:main][Statement@1372ed45]stmt_bidiTransform (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS INTEGER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' NO EXTERNAL ACTION) called
[jcc][Time:2022-01-13-12:22:28.089][Thread:main][Statement@1372ed45]stmt_bidiTransform not enabled (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS INTEGER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' NO EXTERNAL ACTION) called

>>> [jcc][t4] [time:2022-01-13-12:22:28.089][Thread:main]
>>> [tracepoint:10]SetClientPiggybackCommand: flowToServerNeeded() = true
>>> [jcc][t4] [time:2022-01-13-12:22:28.089][Thread:main]
>>> [tracepoint:10]SetClientPiggybackCommand: flowToServerNeeded() = true

[jcc][t4][time:2022-01-13-12:22:28.089][Thread:main][tracepoint:1][Request.flush]
```

I.e. the test program does:

```
SetClientPiggybackCommand: flowToServerNeeded() = true
```

before Request.flush

but whether that is relevant or not I don't know yet

EDIT3:

```
[db2inst1@nya-03 ~]$ ls -lR sqllib/function/
sqllib/function/:
totalt 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     db2iadm1 35 14 sep 14.15 db2json -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/db2json*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     db2iadm1 36 14 sep 14.15 db2psmds -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/db2psmds*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     db2iadm1 35 14 sep 14.15 db2rtsc -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/db2rtsc*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     db2iadm1 34 14 sep 14.15 fpeevm -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/fpeevm*
drwxrwxr-x. 3 db2inst1 db2iadm1 22  1 mar  2021 jar/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     db2iadm1 37 14 sep 14.15 libdb2u.a -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/libdb2u.a*
drwxrwsr-t. 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1  6 23 feb  2021 routine/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     db2iadm1 33 14 sep 14.15 tblpd -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/tblpd*
drwxrwsr-t. 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1 37 14 sep 14.15 unfenced/

sqllib/function/jar:
totalt 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1 28 13 jan 09.48 DB2INST1/

sqllib/function/jar/DB2INST1:
totalt 12
-rw-rw-r--. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 8934 13 jan 09.48 STRINGUTIL.jar

sqllib/function/routine:
totalt 0

sqllib/function/unfenced:
totalt 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root db2iadm1 44 14 sep 14.15 asnqmon -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/unfenced/asnqmon*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root db2iadm1 45 14 sep 14.15 db2gsead -> /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/function/unfenced/db2gsead*
```

Comment: please can you edit the question to include a fragment of the java source showing the package detail and the signature of the method, along with the install_jar() arguments, also indicate in your question if it is not only the same database, but same instance, same authid etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll update

Comment: Ensure that the case of the jarName matches between DDL and `install_jar()` and `replace_jar()`.  You show `EXTERNAL NAME 'StringUtil...` but deploy with jarname `STRINGUTIL`.  There may also be an expectation that the UDF has `throws SQLException` but that may be a different matter.

Comment: I'll have a look but it pussles me why the exact same ddl works for dbeaver, but fails for flyway.

Comment: It must be `public static int quint2uint(String quint) ...`. Not `static int quint2uint(String quint) ...`.

Comment: @mao, I tried EXTERNAL NAME
'STRINGUTIL:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' but it does not seem to make a difference. Still works with clp and dbeaver, but not flyway. I'll try MarkBarinstein suggestion now

Comment: Making the method public did not help either. As of now I'm comparing jdbc traces for flyway and a small testprog that I made. I'll post back any differences I find

Comment: Can you also show the `ls -lR` of the instance sqllib function directory (assuming you have used defaults).

Comment: @mao, I have added ls -lR

Comment: @Lennart  for info, I tried a stub version of your example (with one difference that the function is in the same schema as the authid), with Db2-LUW v11.5.7.0, and flyway community 8.4.1, and the `flyway migrate -X` showed that it deployed successfully.  I will check if the result differs with a different hardcoded schema like you show (NWA).

Comment: @Lennart, also works fine when the DDL has explicit schema NWA. So I cannot recreate your symptom with flyway 8.4.1 (you might be using 8.0.5) and my jre/jdk (I used the jdk that comes with Db2) and my build method.

Comment: I have just upgraded flyway to your version, but the server is currently unavailable so I can't test at the moment. I will also dump all special registers such as current_path etc and compare between the two cases. Once the server is up, I'll report back.

Comment: @mao, I think I have found the cause. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found what caused the problem, atleast I can now create the function without a problem. The root cause is that Flyway appears to:

```
SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = <variable assigned via property -schemas>
```

When this is changed from the instance owner, db2 is unable to find the jar file. If I change the migration to:

```
set CURRENT SCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' @

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) 
RETURNS INTEGER 
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC 
NO SQL 
LANGUAGE JAVA 
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA 
EXTERNAL NAME 'STRINGUTIL:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION @
```

Everything works as expected. I'm not to excited about having to set current_path in the migration (and I'm not sure what effect it will have on Flyway), so I'll have a look if there is another property that can be used to assign a schema for FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY. But this works for now.

EDIT:

The following migration works if I remove -schemas as an argument to Flyway:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

values ('CURRENT SCHEMA', cast(CURRENT SCHEMA as varchar(100))) @

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS INTEGER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT FENCED THREADSAFE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'STRINGUTIL:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint' NO EXTERNAL ACTION @

values NYA.QUINT_2_UINT('aabbccddeef') @

flyway -table="FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" -driver=${driver} -url=jdbc:db2://${host}:${port}/${db} -user=${username} -password=${passwd} -jarDirs=${jarDirs} -locations="filesystem:${upgradedir}" migrate
Flyway is up to date
Flyway Community Edition 8.4.1 by Redgate
Database: jdbc:db2://130.239.91.235:50000/nyax (DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5)
----------------------------------------
Flyway Teams features are enabled by default for the next 27 days. Learn more at https://rd.gt/3A4IWym
----------------------------------------
Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.017s)
Creating Schema History table "DB2INST1"."FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" ...
Current version of schema "DB2INST1": << Empty Schema >>
Migrating schema "DB2INST1" to version "22.223.100.4"
+----------------+----------+
| 1              | 2        |
+----------------+----------+
| CURRENT SCHEMA | DB2INST1 |
+----------------+----------+

+-----+
| 1   |
+-----+
| 274 |
+-----+
```

If I add a specific schema as in:

```
flyway -schemas=NYA_FLYWAY -table="FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" -driver=${driver} -url=jdbc:db2://${host}:${port}/${db} -user=${username} -password=${passwd} -jarDirs=${jarDirs} -locations="filesystem:${upgradedir}" migrate
Flyway is up to date
Flyway Community Edition 8.4.1 by Redgate
Database: jdbc:db2://130.239.91.235:50000/nyax (DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5)
----------------------------------------
Flyway Teams features are enabled by default for the next 27 days. Learn more at https://rd.gt/3A4IWym
----------------------------------------
Creating schema "NYA_FLYWAY" ...
Creating Schema History table "NYA_FLYWAY"."FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" ...
Current version of schema "NYA_FLYWAY": null
Migrating schema "NYA_FLYWAY" to version "22.223.100.4"
+----------------+------------+
| 1              | 2          |
+----------------+------------+
| CURRENT SCHEMA | NYA_FLYWAY |
+----------------+------------+

ERROR: Migration of schema "NYA_FLYWAY" to version "22.223.100.4" failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
```

CURRENT_SCHEMA is changed to NYA_FLYWAY and I assume this is why Db2 can not locate the jar file. If I explicitly set CURRENT_SCHEMA in the migration:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

set CURRENT_SCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' @

values ('CURRENT SCHEMA', cast(CURRENT SCHEMA as varchar(100))) @

...
```

It once again works as expected:

```
flyway -schemas=NYA_FLYWAY -table="FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" -driver=${driver} -url=jdbc:db2://${host}:${port}/${db} -user=${username} -password=${passwd} -jarDirs=${jarDirs} -locations="filesystem:${upgradedir}" migrate
Flyway is up to date
Flyway Community Edition 8.4.1 by Redgate
Database: jdbc:db2://130.239.91.235:50000/nyax (DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5)
----------------------------------------
Flyway Teams features are enabled by default for the next 27 days. Learn more at https://rd.gt/3A4IWym
----------------------------------------
Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.018s)
Current version of schema "NYA_FLYWAY": null
Migrating schema "NYA_FLYWAY" to version "22.223.100.4"
+----------------+----------+
| 1              | 2        |
+----------------+----------+
| CURRENT SCHEMA | DB2INST1 |
+----------------+----------+

+-----+
| 1   |
+-----+
| 274 |
+-----+
```

Also, if I change my little test prog so that it sets current_schema to 'NYA_FLYWAY' before creating the function, I get the same error:

```
java -cp .:/home/lejo0004/db2jcc4.jar tst //nya-03.its.umu.se:50000/nyax db2inst1 $passwd
**** Enter class tst
**** Loaded the JDBC driver
**** Created a JDBC connection to the data source
**** Created JDBC Statement object
CURRENT SCHEMA = NYA_FLYWAY
SQLException information
Error msg: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20204, SQLSTATE=46008, SQLERRMC=NYA.QUINT_2_UINT, DRIVER=4.29.24
SQLSTATE: 46008
Error code: -20204
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20204, SQLSTATE=46008, SQLERRMC=NYA.QUINT_2_UINT, DRIVER=4.29.24
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:815)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.c(k9.java:2844)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.d(k9.java:2828)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.b(k9.java:2188)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.k(ab.java:444)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:102)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.b(p.java:38)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.av.h(av.java:124)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.ak(k9.java:2183)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.a(k9.java:3387)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.e(k9.java:1135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k9.execute(k9.java:1114)
    at tst.main(tst.java:61)
```

FWIW, this can also be reproduced via clp:

```
[db2inst1@nya-03 ~]$ db2 "set current_schema = 'DB2INST1'"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@nya-03 ~]$ db2 "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@nya-03 ~]$ db2 "set current_schema = 'NYA_FLYWAY'"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@nya-03 ~]$ db2 "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NYA.QUINT_2_UINT( I VARCHAR(11))
  RETURNS INTEGER
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME
'StringUtil:se.uhr.nya.commons.db.procedures.Proquint!quint2uint'
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL20204N  The user defined function or procedure "NYA.QUINT_2_UINT" was 
unable to map to a single Java method.  LINE NUMBER=10.  SQLSTATE=46008
```

One might ask why I insist on setting schema- and table- for flyway. As for the table name, the reason is that Flyway otherwise creates them with as quoted identifiers in lowercase. It is a painful experience having to quote these identifiers every time you need to query the table (especially when querying the table from sh). Unfortunately I have not found a way to influence Flyway to behave when it comes to the name for columns, so you will still have to quote them as in:

```
db2 "select \"version\" from ..."
```

I tried manually creating the table, but the flyway fails to handle it. I have not tried it yet, but I may add generated columns or a view for the purpose.

As for the schema name, I've got several products that run their own instance of Flyway. It feels much easier to use the schema + "_FLYWAY" for their instance. I don't want to put the flyway table in the product schema since I run validation scripts on the schema before each committed version.

I also would like to add that I only tried this with flyway community 8.4.1, there may be some other error with flyway community 8.0.5 which I started with

Many thanks to [mao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8290634/mao) and [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10418264/mark-barinstein) for their input (this will probably be removed but now I have added it:-)

EDIT: I ended up adding this to beforeEachMigrate.sql:

```
 --#SET TERMINATOR @
 SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = CURRENT_USER @
```

this file is called automatically by flyway before each migration file is executed.

Comment: I also set flyway.table to uppercase, I `select *` on that table anyway. My `flyway.schemas` value differs from the instance-owner (my `flyway.schemas` = `flyway.defaultSchema` = `flyway.user`), and the UDF also deploys correctly. The authid that performs the `install_jar()` / `replace_jar()` must match the authid that performs the `flyway migrate` actions,   unless I have misunderstood your point.

Comment: db2inst1 both installs the jar and runs the migration. I use the following flags for flyway: `flyway -schemas=NYA_FLYWAY -table="FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" .... migrate. I noticed that when I dumped the special_registers CURRENT_SCHEMA was NYA_FLYWAY. If I change that prior to creating the function it works

Comment: @mao, I added some more info on why I concluded that -schemas is the culprit. I will investigate if it is possible to use another flag than -schemas, but for now I have to attend other things.